# I'm trying to add an image in my CSS

Tags: themes, images, css

I'm trying to add an image in my CSS with the theme folder code, `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>`, which works in HTML but for some reason it's not working in the CSS. Does anyone know why or a solution?

Here's my code:

```
background: url("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bg.jpg");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because php code inside a CSS file is not parsed unless you configure your server to. Just use it as a relative path to the image (as per the CSS file).

`background: url("images/bg.jpg");`

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. Thanks for the explanation!